# how to add a callback function when wiring event?

Tags: jquery

I have a `wireEvents` function that bind javascript with form events. For example,

```
$(document).on('click', '#cancelEdit', cancelEdit);
```

I do it this way because the `#cancelEdit` button is added later from a `jsRender` template. It works fine. When the button is clicked, `cancelEdit` function is called.

```
var cancelEdit = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ...
    };
```

But now I want to add a callback function onto `cancelEdit` like this;

```
var cancelEdit = function (event, callback) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ...
    };
```

How should I update the event wiring statement? Like this?

```
$(document).on('click', '#cancelEdit', cancelEdit('click', cancelEditCallBack));
```

I cannot make it work. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass additional arguments to a callback by using the data parameter.

```
$(document).on('click', '#cancelEdit', {cancelEditCallBack: cancelEditCallBack}, cancelEdit);

var cancelEdit = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.data.cancelEditCallBack();
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

you swapped a function reference with a function invocation.  You should wrap the callback in a second definition now:

```
$(document).on('click', '#cancelEdit', function() {cancelEdit('click', cancelEditCallBack) });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just trigger your own custom event that you can add an event listener to?

```
var cancelEdit = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(event.currentTarget).trigger("mycustomevent")
};

$(document).on("mycustomevent", "#cancelEdit", function (e) {
    // this is your callback
})
```